# How do I use $status returned by pcntl_waitpid()?

Tags: php, parallel-processing, pcntl

I have a parent/worker arrangement going on.  The parent keeps the worker PIDs in an array, constantly checking that they are still alive with the following loop:

```
// $workers is an array of PIDs
foreach ($workers as $workerID => $pid) {
    // Check if this worker still exists as a process
    pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED);

    // If the worker exited normally, stop tracking it
    if (pcntl_wifexited($status)) {
        $logger->info("Worker $workerID exited normally");
        array_splice($workers, $workerID, 1); 
    }

    // If it has a session ID, then it's still living
    if (posix_getsid($pid))⋅
        $living[] = $pid;
}

// $dead is the difference between workers we've started
// and those that are still running
$dead = array_diff($workers, $living);
```

The problem is that `pcntl_waitpid()` is always setting `$status` to 0, so the very first time this loop is run, the parent thinks that all of its children have exited normally, even though they are still running.  Am I using `pcntl_waitpid()` incorrectly, or expecting it to do something that it doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, the child has not exited or stopped.  You added the [`WNOHANG`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-waitpid.php) flag, so it will always return immediately (It tells the function not to wait for an event).  What you should do is check the return value of `pcntl_waitpid` to see if anything of value was returned (assuming that you only want to run the contents of the loop if there's a status change):

```
foreach ($workers as $workerID => $pid) {
    // Check if this worker still exists as a process
    if (pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED)) {
        // If the worker exited normally, stop tracking it
        if (pcntl_wifexited($status)) {
            $logger->info("Worker $workerID exited normally");
            array_splice($workers, $workerID, 1); 
        }
        // If it has a session ID, then it's still living
        if (posix_getsid($pid))⋅
            $living[] = $pid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're indeed "using `pcntl_waitpid()` wrong"  (Note the quotes)

Since you're using `WNOHANG`, *only* if `pcntl_waitpid()` returns the child's PID, you may evaluate what's in `$status`.

See [return values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-waitpid.php) for `pcntl_waitpid()`.